# Calling generic function with 'params' from F# (Observable.StartWith)

Tags: f#

**Edit**: Note that, as Daniel and latkin noted in an answer and a comment below, this question involved a bug in F# that seems to have been fixed in early 2014.

I'm trying to write a curried wrapper for Observable.StartWith.  I'm using the prerelease Reactive Extensions 2.0, and the VS11 beta.  My desired result would be `startWith : 'a -> IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'a>`.  The obvious implementation would be something like:

```
let startWith 
        (value : 'a) 
        (observable : IObservable<'a>) 
        : IObservable<'a> =
    Observable.StartWith(observable, [| value |])
```

The intended overload of Observable.StartWith is `StartWith<'TSource>(source : IObservable<'TSource>, params values: 'TSource[]) : IObservable<'TSource>`.

The compiler throws a confusing error: `This method expects a CLI 'params' parameter in this position. 'params' is a way of passing a variable number of arguments to a method in languages such as C#. Consider passing an array for this argument`.

I *am* passing an array.  I also tried *not* passing an array, by omitting the `[| |]`, which leads to a unique-overload-resolution failure.  (Presumably due to the possibility that `'a` could be `System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler`, matching the other overload.) I also tried using F# 2.0/VS2010, which gives the same result.  I couldn't locate any online discussion of this sort of situation or of the compiler error message.

I can't think of any other way to implement this.  Note that in cases where the type parameter can be determined, it's not a problem.  For instance, `let prependZero : int -> IObservable<int> -> IObservable<int> = fun n o -> o.StartWith(n)` works fine.  But a generic version would be nice.

Comment: There's something odd about type inference surrounding generic param arrays. I emailed fsbugs and will let you know the response.

Comment: The F# team confirmed this is a bug. I included the workarounds they suggested in my answer. It's not likely to be fixed in F# 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a problem with type inference surrounding generic param arrays. Even a simple case, not involving overload resolution, has problems:

```
type A() = 
  static member M<'T>([<ParamArray>] args: 'T[]) = args

//None of these work
let m1 arg = A.M([|arg|])
let m2 args = A.M(args)
let m3<'T> (args:'T[]) = A.M<'T>(args)
```

Non-generic versions work:

```
type B() = 
  static member M([<ParamArray>] args: obj[]) = args

//Both of these are okay
let m1 arg = B.M([|arg|])
let m2 args = B.M(args)
```

#### EDIT

I emailed fsbugs and they responded that this is a bug. Here are some workarounds they suggested.

```
let m1 arg = A.M<obj>([|arg|])
let m2 args = A.M<obj>(args)
let m3 (args:obj[]) = A.M<obj>(args)
let m4 (arg:obj) = A.M<obj>(arg)
let m5 arg1 arg2 = A.M<obj>(arg1,arg2)
let m6 (arg1:'T) = A.M<'T>(arg1)
let m7 (arg1:'T) (arg2:'T) = A.M<'T>(arg1,arg2)
let m8 (arg1:'T) (arg2:'T) = A.M(arg1,arg2)
let m9 (arg1:'T) = A.M(arg1)
let m10<'T> arg1 arg2 = A.M<'T>(arg1,arg2)
let m11<'T> (arg1:'T) (arg2:'T) = A.M<'T>(arg1,arg2)
```

Comment: But the call will work (almost) correctly for `m` having single argument of `'T` -
`let m (arg: 'T) = A.M(arg)`, so `m 5` will return `[|5|]`.
 Also `A.M()` method itself processes variable length argument lists as expected: `A.M(1,2,3,4,5)`
returns `[|1;2;3;4;5|]`. The only idiosyncrasy I can spot is `A.M([|1;2|])` returns `[|1;2|]`
instead of expected `[|[|1;2|]|]`.

Comment: The suggested workaround `m6` seems appropriate in this context.  The following works: `let startWith (value : 'a) (observable : IObservable<'a>) = Observable.StartWith<'a>(observable, value)`, with all type annotations required.

Comment: FYI - this bug has since been fixed. See https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/1

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wrap your single `value` into single element array in order for it to match the last `ParamArray` argument of `Observable.StartWith`, just scalar value is OK ([these samples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11074227/917053) may help to understand why).

But then generic type of `value` creates an ambiguity between two available overloads for `Observable.StartWith`. Disambiguation can be achieved through forcing of [three-agrument overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229372(v=vs.103).aspx) by explicitly placing the implicit type of `IScheduler` from the two-argument overload to the argument list, prepending the `value`, as below:

```
let startWith (value: 'a) observable =
    Observable.StartWith(observable, Scheduler.CurrentThread, value)
```

Now your code should compile and work. A quick check confirms this:

```
Observable.Range(1,2)
|> startWith 10
|> fun x -> x.Subscribe(printf "%d ")
```

outputs as expected `10 1 2`.

**Update**

For Rx 2.0 beta the `Scheduler` reference would be slightly different, the rest of the answer stays unchanged:

```
let startWith (value: 'a) (observable: IObservable<'a>) = 
    Observable.StartWith(observable, Concurrency.Scheduler.CurrentThread, value)
```

Comment: At least with Rx 2.0 beta, your function doesn't work; for whatever reason, the compiler chooses the two-argument overload and constrains `'a` to be of type `CurrentThreadScheduler`.  Using the non-static member function works: `let startWith (value : 'a) (observable : IObservable<'a>) =  observable.StartWith(Scheduler.CurrentThread, value)`.  In this case, 'hard-coding' the scheduler isn't problematic.