# Inconsistent processing of generic ParamArray argument in F#

Tags: .net, f#

Being spotted in context of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11068527/917053) this seemingly
inconsistent behavior can be reproduced as following both in F#2.0 and F#3.0 RC:

```
type Heterogeneous =
    static member Echo([<ParamArray>] args: Object[]) = args

type Generic =  
    static member Echo<'T>([<ParamArray>] args: 'T[]) = args
```

Usage:                                                              Returns:

```
Heterogeneous.Echo 0              // [|0|]                OK
Generic.Echo 0                    // [|0|]                OK
Heterogeneous.Echo (0,1)          // [|0; 1|]             OK
Generic.Echo (0,1)                // [|0; 1|]             OK
Heterogeneous.Echo [|0|]          // [|[|0|]|]            OK?
Generic.Echo [|0|]                // [|0|]                OOPS!!
Heterogeneous.Echo ([|0|],[|1|])) // [|[|0|]; [|1|]|]     OK
Generic.Echo ([|0|],[|1|]))       // [|[|0|]; [|1|]|]     OK
```

Can anyone explain if the observed behavior is a bug, or feature?

**UPDATE:**
This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068724/917053) communicates a confirmation from F# development team that as of now a bug has place in processing of generic type arguments with `ParamArray` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The case is slightly confusing because when you use an array as an actual argument to a parameter marked with `ParamArray`, the language tries to interpret it as if you were passing array to a normal array-typed parameter (so it ignores the `ParamArray` attribute if possible).

In your example, this is possible in the second case:

```
Generic.Echo [|0|]
```

The compiler infers that `'T` is `int` and so you're passing `int[]` to a parameter of type `int[]` and so the compiler ignores `ParamArray` attribute and the method simply gets an array containing `0`.

In the other case, this is not possible:

```
Heterogeneous.Echo [|0|]
```

The method expects a parameter of type `obj[]` and the type of the argument is `int[]`, so the two types cannot be unified (the key is that the compiler does not automatically convert `int[]` to `obj[]`). Since this is not possible, it considers the `ParamArray` attribute and tries to convert `int[]` to `obj` and pass it as a member of `ParamArray` - this is a conversion that the compiler can automatically perform and so you get the result you described.

If you called `Heterogeneous.Echo` with `obj[]` as an argument, then it would behave similarly to `Generic.Echo`. For example:

```
Heterogeneous.Echo [| box 0 |]
```

If you want to go into details, you can look at section 14.4. of the [F# language specification](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=79948). However, the overload resolution rules are pretty complex and so I don't have an exact reference that explains this behaviour - just an informal explanation above.

Comment: Thank you, Tomas! This helps to understand why [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11068951/917053)
disambiguating available `Observable.StartWith()` overloads resolves the problem.